# BufferStrategy show() method is taking upwards of 50 milliseconds to complete for a double buffer, why is it so slow?

Tags: java, time, timer, bufferstrategy

Calling the setup method starts the timers that i have, the one I'm having problems with is render, which takes upwards of 50 milliseconds to complete. far too long for only a double buffer.

```
public void setup() {
    hB = new Rectangle(screenSize.width, screenSize.width);
    player.setRect(new Rectangle(player.getX(), player.getY(), 10, 10));
    this.createBufferStrategy(2);
    strategy = this.getBufferStrategy();
    start();
    startShooting();
    startRender();

}
```

This method starts the timer task and its sole purpose is to call render and about 60 fps

```
public void startRender() {
    startRen = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            render();
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(startRen, 0, 16);
}
```

This is the troublesome method.

```
public void render() {
    g = (Graphics2D) strategy.getDrawGraphics();
    g.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    g.setPaint(Color.black);
    g.drawString("Using " + player.getWeapon().getName(), 10, 20);
    g.drawString("Magazine " + mag, 10, 50);
    g.drawString("Number of AI " + AI.ai.size(), 10, 80);
    g.drawString("Bullets " + Bullet.bullets.size(), 10, 110);
    if (reloading) {
        g.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 100));
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawString("RELOADING", screenSize.width / 2 - 250, screenSize.height / 2);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
    for (Bullet b : Bullet.bullets) {
        g.fillOval((int) b.getX(), (int) b.getY(), 4, 4);
    }
    for (AI a : AI.ai) {
        g.fill(a.getRect());
    }
    g.fill(player.getRect());
    g.dispose();
    strategy.show();
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
}
```

And the only part that takes time is

```
strategy.show()
```

and it takes 50+ milliseconds to just create two buffers, is this common? Will i have to restructure my game to avoid timer task and not use BufferStrategy?